# not work php button to perform the action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've started to use the car dealer script. Unfortunately, this script is not possible to change the language of the visitor's side. Therefore, the first picture of the dropdown menu code, where you can choose between English and German, I copy from administrator panel. When you change the language from English to German and refresh the page, then I again left the English language.

[first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWZtA.png)

In the second picture shows that this time I will present copied the update button, from administrator panel, this time changing the language and press the update button, nothing happens, the language does not change, when I refresh the page, then remains the same English.

[second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FngSx.png)

Language changes only through the administrator panel. What should I do for the visitor himself could change the page language?

this is a drop down menu code, which I browser from admin panel to header file

```
<div class="field">
    <select name="lang">
      <?php foreach(Lang::fetchLanguage() as $lang):?>
      <option value="<?php echo $lang->abbr;?>"<?php if($core->lang == $lang->abbr) echo ' selected="selected"';?>><?php echo $lang->name;?></option>
      <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
</div>
```

this is an update button code

```
<button type="button" name="dosubmit" class="wojo positive button">
    <?php echo Lang::$word->CONF_UPDATE;?>
</button>
<input name="processConfig" type="hidden" value="1" />
```

In my controller.php I found this code

```
/* == Proccess Configuration == */
if (isset($_POST['processConfig'])):
    $core->processConfig();
endif;
```

what should I do to make this feature work, the visitor could itself change the language?

if you need any more info, feel free to ask me, because I'm really new to this world.

Sorry for my English, English language use with google translate

Answer (score 1):

You have to use button type submit, you have button type.

```
<button type="button" name="dosubmit" class="wojo positive button">

<button type="submit" name="dosubmit" class="wojo positive button">Value</button>
```

Comment: nothing worked, the add your code, then after pressing the button, the page just reloads, but the language of a non-replaceable

Comment: Do you have <form action="" method=""> ... </form> or code what you have pasted is your whole code?

Comment: I have this code from config.php <form id="wojo_form" name="wojo_form" method="post"> from the same config.php file took the dropdown menu code and update the button code

Comment: there is no action attribute but Im not sure if it is necessary.

Comment: how this code works? maybe you can look at this code, from which I took the dropdown menu http://codepad.org/WdLyXaJA